# Laravel saying route not defined but it is?

Tags: php, laravel

### InvalidArgumentException Route [welcome.begin] not defined.

But it does? Happens when visiting /welcome/begin and I have double checked the file does exist there.

Routes:

```
<?php

Route::group(['domain' => 'localhost', 'namespace' => 'Frontend'], function () {

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest', 'namespace' => 'Guest'], function() {

        Route::group(['prefix' => 'welcome'], function() {
            Route::any('/begin', ['as' => 'frontend.welcome_begin', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@begin']);
            Route::any('/language', ['as' => 'frontend.welcome_language', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@language']);
            Route::any('/final', ['as' => 'frontend.welcome_final', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@final']);
        });

        Route::any('/', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LandingController@redirect']);
        Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'frontend.login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getView']);
        Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'frontend.login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@onPost']);
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'User'], function() {
        Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'frontend.home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getView']);
    });

});
```

WelcomeController:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Guest;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function begin()
    {
        return route('frontend.welcome.begin');
    }
}
```

View Config:

```
<?php

return [
    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
    ],
    'compiled' => realpath(storage_path('framework/views')),
];
```

There error happens on the "route("frontend.welcome.begin")" line

Comment: why are you using `any`? If the route is just returning a view use `get`. Also that should be `route('frontend.welcome_begin')`

Answer (score 2):

The route does not exist. Your route is named as `frontend.welcome_begin` but you are calling `frontend.welcome.begin`

Your code will need to be: `return route('frontend.welcome_begin');`

I will suggest, having a brief look at the code, to change your welcome routes to be `frontend.welcome.{name}` rather than using an underscore,  as it will follow the rest of the route names you've defined

Answer (score 0):

First you have check if route name is correct

- Open terminal
- Go to project cd PATH_TO_PROJECT
- write `php artisan route:list`
- Check what is correct route name.